# JS Автоматическое заполнение полей

Tags: javascript, веб-программирование

Задача вставить текст в input. Однако этого добиться я не могу. Пробовал следующие способы:

№1 (Текст сбрасывается при создании любого события, например, щелчка кнопкой мыши по форме)

```
inputField.value = 'TEXT';
```

№2 (Аналогично №1)

```
inputField.value = 'TEXT'
inputField.dispatchEvent(new Event('input', { bubbles: true }));
```

№3 (Фокусировка происходит, а вставка текста - нет)

```
inputField.dispatchEvent(new Event('focus', { bubbles: true, cancelable: true }));
const pasteEvent = Object.assign(new Event('paste', { bubbles: true, cancelable: true }), {
    clipboardData: {
        getData: (type = pasteType) => 'PASTED TEXT',
    },
});
inputField.dispatchEvent(pasteEvent);
```

input:

```
<input data-marker="code-input" name="code" maxlength="20" autocomplete="off" placeholder="Ввод" type="text" class="input-input-Zpzc1" value="">
```

Comment: А зачем так сложно через event? Что мешает просто изменить `inputField.value`?

Comment: Данный способ не работает. Объясню почему. Значения хранятся в некоторой модели во время выполнения JavaScript и отображаются в форме. Обновление значения поля не приведет к обновлению модели, поскольку обновления привязаны к входным событиям.

Comment: Я подозреваю, что у события проверяется свойство `isTrusted`, потому что разница в объектах `ClipboardEvent` между ручной вставкой и программной только в этом свойстве. Первый способ работает, второй нет...

Comment: Если дело в этом, что нужен какой то "хак" для того, чтобы установить `isTrusted` в `true`.

Comment: Значит нужно наоборот изменить значение в модели, а уже изменение в модели должно автоматически спровоцировать обновление инпута. Но уж точно не костыли с dispatchEvent городить

Comment: @andreymal Как это можно сделать? Сразу оговорюсь, что сайт принадлежит не мне, я выполняю скрипт на стороннем сайте.

Comment: На счёт модели, такой вывод был сделан из того, что при установке `input.value` любое действие пользователя приводит к сбросу значения. Если использовать событие вставки, то всё работает, но один `input` оказывается проблемным и не позволяет вставить текст.

Comment: может надо юзать не событие `input`, a `change` ?

Comment: напишите такой код `Object.defineProperty(input, 'value', {set: ()=> 1})` , сможете поставить здесь точку остановки и установить где и как меняются данные  (`input` - это dom-элемент)

Comment: @Дмытрык change не помогает. _" сможете поставить здесь точку остановки и установить где и как меняются данные"_ - Как я могу поставить точку останова в Chrome DevTools -> Console? У меня скрипт не в расширении используется. Просто должен выполнятся на стороннем сайте.

Comment: @Дмытрык Я нашёл [место в коде](https://pastebin.com/cZTesEVU), которое отвечает за установку `value`. [Данный код](https://pastebin.com/WQUbW5Nk) работает (то есть поле успешно заполняется, и его значение не сбрасывается), но у меня возникает следующая ошибка: `react-dom.45babd8177c86659bebf.js:formatted:415 Uncaught TypeError: Illegal invocation at Object.set (react-dom.45babd8177c86659bebf.js:formatted:415) at <anonymous>:2:54`

Comment: @Дмытрык _"Я нашёл место в коде, которое отвечает за установку value"_ - Значения переменных в момент установки свойства через `input.value = '...'`: e - вводимый текст, i - функция set, которая видимо была по умолчанию назначена на элемент, до переопределения.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor(HTMLInputElement.prototype, "value").set.call(inputField, "TEXT");
```

Comment: пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]

Comment: Да, так исключения не происходит и всё работает.