# CEF Перезапуск соединения

Tags: c#, веб-программирование, браузер, cefsharp

Что необходимо для того чтобы сайт видел каждое новое соединение как соединения с разными компьютерами? Можно очистить файлы cookies, сменить внешний IP-адрес, перезагрузить страничку. Есть ли ещё пути, кроме cookies, по которым сайт может понять, что несмотря на изменение IP-адреса, соединение установлено с уже ранее подключавшимся компьютером.

В браузере настроено сохранение кэша. Может ли в кэше сохранятся какая то информация о завершённых сессиях?

```
Cef.GetGlobalCookieManager().DeleteCookies();
ChangeIp();
WebBrowser.Reload();
// Воспримет ли сайт после этого нас как нового пользователя?
```

Comment: Активные TCP соединения находятся в ответственности операционной системы, а не браузера. Браузер только может решать, переиспользовать открытые или закрывать и пересоздавать. С другой стороны, 2 открытые страницы в браузере - это отдельные TCP соединения, если это HTTP/1.x, а если HTTP/2, данные могут передаваться одному серверу с разных страниц через одно соединение. Но мне кажется, вы хотите странного. Зачем это нужно? Наверняка у вас HTTP/1.1 и для каждого обновления страницы и каждого нового запроса к серверу и так устанавливается новое соединение. Кеш здесь вообще никаким боком.

Comment: Другими словами, перезапускать вам нечего, и так все перезапускается само.

Comment: @aepot _"Зачем это нужно?"_ - Работа в нескольких аккаунтах например. _"Наверняка у вас HTTP/1.1 и для каждого обновления страницы и каждого нового запроса к серверу и так устанавливается новое соединение."_ - Даже при HTTP/2, если я меняю настройки прокси в браузере, неужели соединение обязательно не пересоздаётся?

Comment: @aepot _"Но мне кажется, вы хотите странного. "_ - Нельзя допустить, чтобы сайт понял, что входы выполняются с одного компьютера.

Comment: Я хотел узнать достаточно ли очистить cookies и сменить IP для этого. Сбрасывается ли содержимое session storage и local storage.

Comment: _если я меняю настройки прокси в браузере, неужели соединение обязательно не пересоздаётся?_ пересоздается. _Нельзя допустить_ критериев поймать браузер полно, от записи данных в хранилище и куки до создания отпечатка по заголовкам HTTP и окружению браузера с помощью сканирования яваскриптом, об этом книгу целую можно написать, кстати, наверное кто-то уже написал, поищите. Например гугл влегкую отличает хром с селениумом от нормального хрома. _достаточно ли очистить cookies и сменить IP для этого_ нет. _Сбрасывается ли содержимое_ сбрасывается, если вы сбрасываете, по умолчанию - не должно.

Comment: @aepot _"критериев поймать браузер полно, от записи данных в хранилище и куки"_ - Куки перед переподключением я очищаю, а на счёт записи данных в хранилище можно поподробнее? _"до создания отпечатка по заголовкам HTTP"_ - Изощрённые способы исключим из рассмотрения. _"сбрасывается, если вы сбрасываете, по умолчанию - не должно"_ - То есть для надёжности не мешало бы выполнить `localStorage.clear(); sessionStorage.clear();`?

Comment: А вы попробуйте, я CEF руками не трогал, просто предполагаю что он нормальный и ведет себя как обычный браузер. Создайте скрипт, который что-то пишет в хранилище. И проверяйте читая записанное.

Comment: @aepot _"критериев поймать браузер полно, от записи данных в хранилище ..."_ -  Вы имели ввиду local storage и session storage? _"Создайте скрипт, который что-то пишет в хранилище. И проверяйте читая записанное."_ - После перезагрузки страницы значения сохранились как в local так и в session storage. Получается нужно чистить куки и хранилище перед перезагрузкой.

Comment: @aepot Вы случайно не встречались с автоматическим заполнением форм на вебсайтах?

Comment: Автоматическое заполнение - понятие растяжимое.

Comment: @aepot Возможно и в [данной теме](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1342185/js-%d0%90%d0%b2%d1%82%d0%be%d0%bc%d0%b0%d1%82%d0%b8%d1%87%d0%b5%d1%81%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%b5-%d0%b7%d0%b0%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%bb%d0%bd%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5-%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%bb%d0%b5%d0%b9) вы сможете дать направление куда копать.